# Reduce Background in a Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wamp

I have a Wordpress page with have a big background in green color, but I don't want those edges, because they take away space for the text.
How I can remove or at least reduce it?
I use Catch Box theme.
I try write code in Aditional CSS, but don't work for now.

[image]

Comment: Try your browser inspector to see what CSS is affecting the page.

Comment: Well, in the inspector appears that the white "background" is a <div>. The green background is <body>. Perphaps if I can change the size of this <div>, I can gain more space to texts.